# Export Python dataframe into CSV

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have a dataframe x with the size of ( 2000, 3000) . I would like to export it into CSV to use in R. I tried this code:

```
 x.to_csv("ab.csv", sep='\t')
```

However, when I open in R by the code:

```
 data = read.csv(".data/ab.csv")
```

The size of data is (2000,1) because the CSV file can not separate into 3000 columns. Is there any solution to keep the same size after exporting ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the seperator inside read.csv()

Comment: don't you have to specify a proper (`\t`) delimiter?

Answer (score 2):

By using the parameter `sep='\t'` you have written a "CSV" which uses tab to separate fields instead of a comma. You could either remove the parameter and write a normal CSV, or use the `sep="\t"` argument for `read.csv` in R. If there's no reason to use tab then I would suggest the former option.

Answer (score 1):

try reading the csv file like this

```
data = read.csv(".data/ab.csv",sep="\t")
```

Your csv uses `\t` to separate each value, using the `sep` pararmeter you have to specify the separator when opening it